# Angular Material Stepper: How to set to 'not active' all steps?

Tags: angular, angular-material, stepper

I have an angular component with the following view:

```
<div class="stepper-container" *ngIf="steps">
  <mat-horizontal-stepper *ngIf="!isVertical" [selectedIndex]="stepIndex" (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)" #stepper class="stepper" [style.width.%]="long">
    <mat-step *ngFor="let step of steps; let i = index">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>{{step}}  <mat-icon>check</mat-icon></ng-template>
    </mat-step>
  </mat-horizontal-stepper>
</div>
```

I would like to have all my steps 'not active' instead of having the first one (selectedIndex = 0).

I have tried using selectedIndex = -1 but once you click the step, it triggers an error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'interacted' of undefined

This is the logic:

```
...

  steps: string[];
  bpSub: Subscription;
  isVertical: boolean;
  verticalStepperBreakpoint = breakpoints.verticalStepperBreakpoint;

  @Input()
  set stepperSteps(value: string[]) {
    this.steps = value;
  }
  @Input() stepIndex: number;
  @Input() long: number;
  @Input() completed: boolean;
  @Output() selectedStepIndexChanged: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private bpObserver: BreakpointObserver) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bpSub = this.bpObserver
      .observe([`(max-width: ${this.verticalStepperBreakpoint}px)`])
      .subscribe((state: BreakpointState) => {
        this.setVerticalStepper(state.matches);
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.bpSub) {
      this.bpSub.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  selectionChange(e: StepperSelectionEvent) {
    this.selectedStepIndexChanged.emit(e.selectedIndex);
  }

...
```

Comment: Did you try giving selectedIndex as `null`?

Comment: Basically you are fighting against logic. If you are in the step number X then the selectedIndex will be X-1. What are you really trying to achieve? Maybe there's another approach to accomplish it.

Comment: @JoseGuzman to be honest I think you are right my friend